# Not sure how to plot this, a scatter plot with categories

Tags: r, excel, plot

I have the following dataset

```
SIZE ALG1 ALG2 ALG3
  A   2    3    5
  A   3    2    1
  A   1    2    2
  B   10  10    11
  B   12  12   12
```

I'd like a plot having as a horizontal axis the SIZE column and as Y values the series ALG1 ALG2 ALG3.

E.g.

[image]

How can I get it wit Excel (actually OOCALC) or R?

In general I get the SIZE values repeated on the x-axis, which appears then much longer.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your data frame is called `df1`.

You have to convert it in a long format using `reshape2::melt`

```
melt(df1) -> dfmelt

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=dfmelt, aes(x=SIZE, y=value)) + geom_jitter(aes(color=variable))
```

or, more simply and quickly:

```
qplot(data=dfmelt, x=SIZE, y=value, geom="jitter", color=variable)
```

If you just want the points without "jittering" them:

```
qplot(data=dfmelt, x=SIZE, y=value, geom="point", color=variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

In R you could do it as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(
   size = c(rep('A', 3), rep('B', 2)),
   alg1 = c(2,3,1,10,12),
   alg2 = c(3,2,2,10,12),
   alg3 = c(5,1,2,11,12)
   )

plot(alg1 ~ jitter(as.numeric(size)), data = df,
  xlim = c(0.5, 2.5), ylim = c(0, 14), col = 'red',
  axes = FALSE, xlab = 'Size', ylab = 'Alg')
points(alg2 ~ jitter(as.numeric(size)), data = df, col = 'blue')
points(alg3 ~ jitter(as.numeric(size)), data = df, col = 'black')
axis(side = 2)
axis(side = 1, at = c(1, 2), labels = c('A', 'B'))
legend(x = 2, y = 4, legend = c('alg1', 'alg2', 'alg3'),
  col = c('red', 'blue', 'black'), lty = 1)
```